# Unable to build Card-View

Tags: android, android-studio, themes, android-cardview

I am trying to insert a card view in my layouts, but it is giving this rendering error.

```
Missing styles.
Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout,
or fix the theme style references.
Failed to find style with id 0x7fff001a in current theme.
```

I have already included this in the app's gradle:

- **compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'**

Also, the theme that I am using in styles is

- **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar**

The styles.xml is here:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="cardStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>
</style>
```

The cardview is here:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:elevation="5dp"/>
```

The error message talks about style with id 0x7fff001a. What is it referring to?

Comment: did you set the theme for the activity in and manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `Gradle Clean` and `Rebuild` and `Sync all Gradle files`. After that  `restart` Android Studio, and go to:

[image]

When you create the style incorrectly or from an existing style, this problem usually occurs. So select the "Graphical Layout" select "AppTheme"-->The tab with a blue star. And select any of the predefined style. In my case "Light" which should resolve the problem.

In case still the problems remain just temporary remove `<item name="cardStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>` from your theme and give a try.

Comment: Thank you Anoop.. that worked.. Thanks alot... and here i was pulling my hairs :D :D